# perl connectivity issue for newbie

Tags: oracle, perl

friends could one of the perl expert tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm still learning perl so newbie with this..whatever I do my connection string doesn't work.

1. trying to connect oracle database with perl script with below argument on cmd prompt.

   `$ list_tables /@testdb`
2. Query dba_tables and list tables of user ABC
3. Also get output in logfile

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w      
use strict;
use Getopt::Std;
use OracleAgent;
use OracleLoginString;

my exitStatus = 0;
my %options = ();
my $oracleLogin;

getopts("o",\%options);

if (defined $options{o}) {
    $oracleLogin = $options{o};
}
else {
    exitWithError());
}

my $db = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:',$oracleLogin,'')
    or die "Can't connect to Oracle database: $DBI::errstr\n";

exit($exitStatus);
```

Basically when I execute script I just want to provide instance name and not password.

I can connect from sqlplus prompt without password since using oracle login e.g. `$sqlplus "/@testdb"`

Comment: did you install DBD::Oracle, and the oracle client?

Comment: yes everything is there and there are also many scripts running on same host. I can connect by providing username and password but that's not best option.

Comment: basically idea is to provide script name with dbname e.g. `$./list_name -o /@testdb`

Answer (score 0):

1. add [DBD::Oracle](http://p3rl.org/DBD%3a%3aOracle)

   ```
   use DBD::Oracle;
   ```
2. Write a proper connection string:

   ```
   my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:host=$host;sid=$sid", $user, $passwd);
   ```